# Referance error showing, ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a gridview cotrol which is [populated from database using c#.The source is

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdAddressbook" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" width="100%" Border="0px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="27%">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="Server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' Style="cursor: pointer; display: block;"
                                    onclick="SelectAddressRow(this)"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email Address" ItemStyle-Width="40%">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblEmailId" runat="server" ToolTip='<%# Eval("EmailId") %>' Text='<%# Convert.IsDBNull (Eval("EmailId")) ? "" : ( ((String)Eval("EmailId")).Length >25 ? ((String)Eval("EmailId")).Substring(0,25) + "..." :((String)Eval("EmailId")))  %>'
                                    Style="cursor: pointer; display: block;" onclick="SelectAddressRow(this)"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Organization" ItemStyle-Width="33%">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblOrganization" runat="server" Text='<%# Convert.IsDBNull (Eval("Organization")) ? " &nbsp;" : ((String)Eval("Organization")) == "" ? " &nbsp;" : Eval("Organization") %>'
                                    Style="cursor: pointer; display: block;" onclick="SelectAddressRow(this)"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I want to make the background of the particular row that is clicked to Red colour.I have a javascript function for that

```
function SelectAddressRow(column) {
   $($(column).parent()).parent().css({ "background-color": "red" });
}
```

The source appear after rendering like this

```
<tbody>
<tr>
<th scope="col">Name</th>
<th scope="col">Email Address</th>
<th scope="col">Organization</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width:27%;">
<span id="grdAddressbook_ctl02_lblName" style="cursor: pointer; display: block;" onclick="SelectAddressRow(this)">ajish</span>
</td>
<td style="width:40%;">
<span id="grdAddressbook_ctl02_lblEmailId" style="cursor: pointer; display: block;" onclick="SelectAddressRow(this)" title="ajish@yahoo.com">ajish@yahoo.com</span>
</td>
<td style="width:33%;">
<span id="grdAddressbook_ctl02_lblOrganization" style="cursor: pointer; display: block;" onclick="SelectAddressRow(this)">  </span>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

but when ever I click on the row an error is showig in firebug that

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
$($(column).parent()).parent().css({ "background-color": "red" });
```

Comment: You didn't add jQuery, or somehow is overwriting $.

Comment: whether the script is included before jQuery

Answer (score 2):

**1. First**

Check have you referenced Jquery scripts.

**2.  Second**

If yes, then Check for jQuery Conflict .And try to use 'jQuery' istead of '$'